# Issues distributing Flutter app from XCode 13 (AppStore)

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I develop the app on a windows PC and then I send the file I'm using to a Mac from the company. From there I did an upload to the AppStore last week (after some problems) with a first Mac. I made some changes on the App and now I tried to upload again from another Mac. This time I am able to do the whole process without any mistakes but after clicking Distribute App and accepting everything and no Issues on XCode I get an email saying "The build status of MyApp (version) has changed to Invalid Binary". Inside the message they say the bundle id is already taken. I've checked this and on the details (Archive window) of my app I've got the correct identifier, same as in developer page from apple, and the team is also the same.

Of course all this is with automatic signing. And certificate is for distribution (I don't really know how to confirm, but this one is available)

I've got a couple questions about this.
Do builds have to be the immediate following? I mean, I can't jump from 1 to 4, for example?
I deduce version and build is always taken from the runner configuration on XCode.
Should I always submit the same folder? Instead of making new copies of the version.
On a desperate attemp of trying things I created a new version from App Store Connect plus sign in my App.
Can I delete it? Can I use the same version I named it on XCode to upload? Can I use any other named version to upload?

What else should I try? Next thing I'd do would be deleting the Bundle ID and creating a new one, but that doesn't solve my problems on the long term.

I am using:
XCode 13.2.1
macOS Monterey 12.2.1

I tried changing versions and builds on Xcode, expecting to create the correct one.
I tried from an old mac to see if it was that I haven't got the good certificates, expecting a correct upload.